# Deploying next js to production (on VM)

Tags: jss, nextjs

Is there any guidelines from Sitecore that shows how I can deploy my next app to a VM.

The documentation website is talking about Vercel mainly, but what if I want to deploy it to a windows VM, assume that I've the CM / CD server, then I want to deploy my next app on a server that has node js installed.

My app is not using dockers, I just want to deploy my app to a node server where it can be accessible from outside through a custom domain, With normal MVC we used to deploy it on IIS and adjust the host file to use a custom domain for testing, if I want to achieve this with next app what tools I need.

Comment: Next.js is just a node application. There isn't anything special about it for Sitecore. It just needs node to run.